# update em 2 tabelas com calculo e update de campo mantendo o anterior

Tags: php, sql

Pessoal estou tentado fazer um update pegando o valor de outra tabela, porém os dados da segunda tabela não são enviados.

To passando a ID da carta:

```
<a href=index.php?pag=shopcomprar&id={$row['ID']} '>[COMPRAR]</a>
```

E tentando inserir em outra tabela comparando resultados, onde `m_duelos = dinheiro` que o usuário tem:

```
//selecionando dados da tabela carta
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cartas WHERE ID='$id'");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH)) {
$preço = $row['preço'];
$nome = $row['nome'];

} 

//selecionando dados da tabela usuarios
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM novo_usuarios WHERE ID='$id_user'");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH)) {
$marcas = $row['m_duelo'];
} 


// CONDICOE //
if($preço>$marcas){ 


//nesta parte os dados da segunda parece não estar pegando so os da 1 //
$result3 = mysql_query("UPDATE novo_usuarios SET m_duelo='$marcas - $preço' , deck1=(deck1' + <br>$nome<br>) WHERE ID='$id_user' ");
echo " A compra da carta <b>$nome</b> $marcas foi efetuado com sucesso. <br>Você já pode usa-la em duelos RPG.<br> Voce ainda possui $row2[m_duelo] Marcas de Duelo";
//SE DER TUDO OK //



// FECHAMENTO //
}else{echo "<center>Você não tem marcas suficiente para comprar esta carta.";}
```

Para tentar ilustrar o que estou querendo com isso, quero que quando clicar em comprar seja feito:

1. a comparação entre o valor da carta e o dinheiro que o usuário tem;
2. update do dinheiro que o usuário tem - o valor da carta;
3. pegar o nome da carta e inserir no campo deck 1 ( porém esse campo será acrescentado, não irá apagar o valor que tem lá, só irá inserir algo depois do que já tem).

tentei fazer usando os codigos acima porem não funciona, alguém me da uma luz?

Comment: Alguma mensagem de erro?

Comment: Tome muito cuidado com este seu código, ele é uma festa para um SQL Injection. Você deveria manipular e checar melhor o valor do $id antes de sair atribuindo ele no query

Comment: De onde vem essas variáveis que você está usando nas consultas? O seu código parece bem susceptível à injeção de SQL.

Comment: Só consegui notar um aspa simples depois de deck1 não fechada e aqueles `( )` estranhos no update,`deck1=(deck1' + <br>$nome<br>)`

Comment: Paulo, como chegar o $id ?  NULL USER a variavel $id vem do link de cima to pegando ela com $id = $_GET["id"]; ela e o id da tabela de cartas, quanto ao ataques ainda sou novato em php mais vou procurar mais seguranca aceito dicas:) PERDEU, mais a forma é mesmo essa que estou fazendo ? nao precisa de ( ) pq quero pegar o valor existente e acrecentar mais dados aos que existem la

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu código está vulnerável a SQL INJECTION. 

E melhor você já aprender o [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.pdo.php). Menos dor de cabeça no futuro :)

Sobre seu código. Seu select2 estava sobre escrevendo o primeiro. por ter o mesmo nome.

Testa ae:

```
    <?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cartas WHERE ID='$id'");
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH)) {
   $preco = $row['preço'];
   $nome = $row['nome'];
} 
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM novo_usuarios WHERE ID='$id_user'"); 
 while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2, MYSQL_BOTH)) {
   $marcas = $row2['m_duelo'];
} 

if($preco >= $marcas){ 
   $calculo = ($marcas - $preco);
   $deck1   = "deck1 adicionou <br>".$nome."<br>";
  //nesta parte os dados da segunda parece não estar pegando so os da 1 //
  $result3 = mysql_query("UPDATE novo_usuarios SET m_duelo='$calculo', deck1=concat('(', coalesce('$nome', '')') WHERE ID='$id_user' ");
  echo " A compra da carta <b>".$nome."</b> ".$marcas." foi efetuado com sucesso. <br>Você já pode usa-la em duelos RPG.<br> Voce ainda possui ".$marcas." Marcas de Duelo";
}else{
  echo "<center>Você não tem marcas suficiente para comprar esta carta.";
}
?>
```

Comment: Cara, seu concat está errado. Você esqueceu de fecha-lo.

Answer (score 1):

Você trocou uma ' e um + de lugar e as aspas em m_duelo não são necessárias (Isso considerando que o campo m_muelo é numeric... Se for varchar use as aspas. Essa seria a query correta:

```
UPDATE novo_usuarios SET m_duelo=$marcas - $preço , deck1=concat('(', coalesce(deck1, ''), '<br>$nome<br>)') WHERE ID='$id_user';
```

Indo além da pergunta:

- Para verificar se o usuário foi informado você pode fazer um if isset($_GET["id"]).
- Se este código for apenas estudo está ok, mas sugiro que estude sobre Prepared Statements. Não recomendo que programe assim na real.